# matrix in normal coordinates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inverse, hyperbolic-functions

Writing the matrix $ \begin{pmatrix}
    -\frac{k}{\gamma} & \frac{k}{\gamma}&0&0&0&\cdots&0&0&0&0   \\
    \frac{k}{\gamma} &-2\frac{k}{\gamma}& \frac{k}{\gamma}&0&0&\cdots&0&0&0&0 \\
  0&\frac{k}{\gamma} &-2\frac{k}{\gamma}& \frac{k}{\gamma}&0&\cdots&0&0&0&0 \\
  \vdots&\vdots &\vdots& \vdots&\vdots&\cdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots \\
  0&0&0&0&0&\cdots&\frac{k}{\gamma} &-2\frac{k}{\gamma}& \frac{k}{\gamma}&0\\
  0&0&0&0&0&\cdots&0&\frac{k}{\gamma} &-2\frac{k}{\gamma} & \frac{k}{\gamma} \\
  0&0&0&0&0&\cdots&0&0&\frac{k}{\gamma'} & \frac{k}{\gamma'}
 \end{pmatrix}$ in terms of normal coordinates. How does one begin ? It represents the matrix of a set of differential equations.

Comment: What are normal coordinates? The matrix seems to be a discretisation of a laplacian with weird boundary conditions.